# Como eu faço pra achar o maior número lido e o menor número lido?

Tags: python-3.x

Como eu faço pra achar o maior número lido e o menor número lido?
Tentei o `max` e o `min` e não deu certo.

```
arquivo = open('notas_alunos.txt', 'r')

lista_notas = []

conteudo = arquivo.readline()

linha = conteudo[:-1].split(';')
lista_notas.append(linha)

while conteudo:
   conteudo = arquivo.readline()
   linha = conteudo[:-1].split(';')
   lista_notas.append(linha)


arquivo.close()


lista_notas.pop()

for elemento in range(0, len(lista_notas)):
    matricula = lista_notas[elemento][0]  
    nota_1    = float(lista_notas[elemento][1])    
    nota_2    = float(lista_notas[elemento][2])  
    nota_3    = float(lista_notas[elemento][3])  
    nota_4    = float(lista_notas[elemento][4])             
    media     = (nota_1 + nota_2 + nota_3 + nota_4)/4  
    print('{0} {1:.2f} {2:.2f} {2:.2f} {3:.2f} {4:.2f}'.format(matricula,nota_1,nota_2,nota_3,nota_4,media))
```

Comment: Sempre procure na documentação oficial. Veja o tópico sobre estrutura de dados: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html e observe que em listas não existem o "max" e o "min". Você pode ordenar com "sort", por exemplo: lista.sort() e o parâmetro booleano "reverse" definirá se a ordenação será crescente ou decrescente e também poderá definir uma chave para a sua ordenação, por exemplo: lista.sort(reverse=True, key=ordenarExtensao) ou lista.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda value: value['valor'])

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

se você conseguiu utilizar o método sugerido pelo LGregianin basta pegar o primeiro ou último elemento da lista, a depender do valor do parâmetro reversed dentro do método sort.

Caso reversed esteja true, a lista será ordenada do maior valor, portanto no índice 0, até o menor valor, no indice -1. No caso contrário é so inverter as posições.

De qualquer forma, não ficou totalmente claro se você quer saber os maiores e menores valores lidos no total ou quer a maior/menor média, etc. Se você puder detalhas mais o problema poderemos de ajudar de forma mais precisa.

Comment: Entendi, porém como eu faria pra achar o maior e menor valor ?

Comment: Deu certo gente, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Bom, existem algumas formas de achar o menor e maior valor de um conjunto de números. O ideal é você entender a lógica e não apenas copiar uma resposta pronta.
A maneira que eu considero mais simples é colocar todos os valores a serem analisados em um array, fazer a varredura dele e fazer a atribuição baseando-se na condicional `array[posição] < menorValor ?` ou `array[posição] > maiorValor ?`

```
menor = arr[0];
maior = arr[0];

for(int i=0; i < arr.tamanho; i++ ){
    if(arr[i] > maior) 
        maior = arr[i];
    if(arr[i] < menor)
        menor = arr[i];             
}
```

Cada vez que a varredura encontrar um valor menor(ou maior) que o valor da váriavel atual, o valor será substituído pelo mesmo.
(Tente aplicar a lógica à sua linguagem)